# Remove shipping fee in cart page in woocommerce 3.0?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to exclude the shipping fee, if there's any, in the cart page. Total should only display the actual total of items and discounts or coupons if there's any.

[Please see visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFgS9.png)

I tried adding this code in function.php but only hide the shipping details but the fee is still being added in Total.

```
function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart( $show_shipping ) {
    if( is_cart() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $show_shipping;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
```

[My Cart Page after above code - doesn't remove fee from total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZMu9.png)

Comment: Some more context is needed here.

Comment: you simply need to desactivate shipping in woocommerce option. Use the Free shipping

Comment: @TemaniAfif that doesn't work either. If I select a shipping option with fee in the checkout page and return back to Cart Page, the fee adds up to Total

Comment: so you need to have shipping but you want to force the shipping to 0 in cart, right ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif correct. 0 shipping fee in Cart Page. The actual fee should only display in the Checkout page.

Comment: ok, i may have a work around for this using CSS. Can you provde the link of the website in the question ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif im not sure if I wanna do that using css. Would there be a workaround using woocommerce hooks?

Comment: @TemaniAfif plus, my site is not yet open for public.

Comment: i don't think so, as the shipping apply in all the site and it's diffuclt to force them. My idea was to only show the subtotal part and using CSS i change the word Subtotal with Total. So in the cart page you only have the subtotal which doesn't include the fee and its name is total.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see. A good solution but that wouldn't work with coupons.